# Add a substring within string interpolation if condition is met

Tags: ruby, literals

I am given an array, and must join certain items corresponding to each element with spaces depending on the element:

1. If the element is a string `string` or an array of the form `[string]`, include `string` in the output.
2. If the element is an array of the form `[string1, string2]`, then include `"--string1"` in the output if `string1` is longer than one character, or `"-string1"` otherwise. Then include `"string2"` in the result.

So `["cat",["dog","fish"],["cow"]]` would output `"cat --dog fish cow"` and `[["a","bat"],"mouse"]` would output `"-a bat mouse"`.

Someone else wrote the following code:

```
def args_to_string args
  args.map{ |i,j| j ? "#{?-if i[1]}-#{i} #{j}" : i}*" "
end
```

- I understand that the splat `*` at the end means that it's okay for the block just to receive one parameter, and will be `nil` in that case.
- Then there's a ternary if-then statement. The next line:

  ```
  "#{?-if i[1]}-#{i} #{j}"
  ```

  includes an extra hyphen if `i` has a second character, I think.
- What can go in between the braces in this `#{}`? How do I include a specific string, only if a condition is met?
- And in the above example, why does the hyphen have a question mark in front of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the splat * at the end means that it's okay for the block just to receive one parameter

No. `Array#*` with a string argument is the same as `join`.

> How do I include a specific string only if a condition is met?

You do it like:

```
"#{"foo" if some_contition}"
```

It is actually used in the code as `#{?-if i[1]}`.

> why does the hyphen have a question mark in front of it?

To save characters. It is a literal for single character strings. `?-` is equivalent to `"-"`.

In short, please read the manual.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try stepping through the calculations.

```
args = ["cat", ["dog","fish"], ["cow"]]
```

The operative line is

```
args.map { |i,j| j ? "#{ ?- if i[1] }-#{ i } #{ j }" : i } * " "
```

Let's break that down.

```
enum = args.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["cat", ["dog", "fish"], ["cow"]]:map>
```

We can convert this enumerator to an array see the three elements it will pass to the block.

```
enum.to_a
  #=> ["cat", ["dog", "fish"], ["cow"]]
```

The first element of `enum` is passed to the block and the values of the block variables are determined using *parallel (or multiple) assignment*:

```
i,j = enum.next
  #=> "cat"
i #=> "cat"
j #=> nil

str = "#{ ?- if i[1] }-#{ i } #{ j }"
  #=> "#{ "-" if "a" }-cat "   Note "#{ nil }" => "" 
  #=> "--cat "    
j ? str : i
  #=> nil ? "--cat " : "cat"
  #=> "cat"
```

So `"cat"` maps to `"cat"`.

Note that `i[1] => nil` when `i` is a one-character string, which, though not used in the example, is important. Next, the second element of `enum` is passed to the block.

```
i,j = enum.next
  #=> ["dog", "fish"] 
i #=> "dog" 
j #=> #=> "fish" 
str = "#{ ?- if i[1] }-#{ i } #{ j }"
  #=> "#{ "-" if "o" }-dog fish"
  #=> "--dog fish" 
j ? str : i
  #=> "fish" ? "--dog fish" : "dog"
  #=> "--dog fish"
```

`["dog", "fish"]` is therefore mapped to `"--dog fish"`.

```
i,j = enum.next
  #=> ["cow"] 
i #=> "cow" 
j #=> nil 
str = "#{ ? - if i[1] }-#{ i } #{ j }"
  #=> "#{ "-" if "o" }-cow "
  #=> "--cow " 
j ? str : i
  #=> nil ? "--cow " : "cow 
  #=> "cow"
```

`"cow"` is mapped to `"cow"`.

```
enum.next
  #=>StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

So we are finished with `map`. I have shown

```
a = enum.each { |i,j| j ? "#{?-if i[1]}-#{i} #{j}" : i}
  #=> ["cat", "--dog fish", "cow"]
```

which is how

```
args.map{ |i,j| j ? "#{?-if i[1]}-#{i} #{j}" : i}
  #=> ["cat", "--dog fish", "cow"]
```

is implemented. The last step is

```
a * " "
  #=> a.join(" ")
  #=> "cat --dog fish cow"
```

since [Array#*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-2A) is "equivalent to `ary.join(str)`".

Comment: I can tell your answers by their length before scrolling all the way down to see your icon.

Comment: @sawa, only when it's one of my gory-detail answers, reserved mainly for Ruby-newbies.